# QLabel isn't transparent when rendered on item delegate (QStyledItemDelegate)

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I have strange problem. I have item delegate inherit from `QStyledItemDelegate`. The background color is gradient color that looks like this:

```
void ItemDelegate::paintActiveOverlay( QPainter* painter,
                                       qreal x,
                                       qreal y,
                                       qreal w,
                                       qreal h ) const 
{
    QPalette palette;
    QColor highlightColor = palette.color(QPalette::Highlight);
    QColor backgroundColor = palette.color(QPalette::Base);
    const float animation = 0.25;
    const int gradientRange = 16;

    QColor color2 = QColor::fromHsv(
        highlightColor.hue(),
        (int) (backgroundColor.saturation() * (1.0f - animation) + 
        highlightColor.saturation() * animation),
        (int) (backgroundColor.value() * (1.0f - animation) + 
        highlightColor.value() * animation) );

    QColor color1 = QColor::fromHsv(
        color2.hue(),
        qMax(color2.saturation() - gradientRange, 0),
        qMin(color2.value() + gradientRange, 255) );

    QRect rect( (int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);

    painter->save();
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);

    QLinearGradient linearGradient(0, 0, 0, rect.height());
    linearGradient.setColorAt(0.0, color1);
    linearGradient.setColorAt(1.0, color2);

    painter->setBrush(linearGradient);
    painter->drawRect(rect);
    painter->restore();
}
```

It's called from the paint method also in the `ItemDelegate` constructor I have set `QLabel` like this:

```
 QRect rect(40, 30, 401, 31);
 Qt::TextInteractionFlags flags =     
      Qt::LinksAccessibleByKeyboard | 
      Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse    |
      Qt::TextBrowserInteraction    |
      Qt::TextSelectableByKeyboard  |
      Qt::TextSelectableByMouse;
 Qt::TextFormat txtFormat = Qt::PlainText;
 
 pTextEdit_title = new QLabel();
 pTextEdit_title->setTextFormat(txtFormat);
 pTextEdit_title->setTextInteractionFlags(flags);
 pTextEdit_title->setGeometry(rect);
```

and in the paint method of the `ItemDelegate` i set the `QLabel` to render like this:

```
  pTextEdit_title->setText(Title);
  QRect TextEditRect(option.rect.x()+THUMB_WIDTH+THUMB_WIDTH+PADDING, option.rect.y() ,
  pTextEdit_title->width(), pTextEdit_title->height());
  QPixmap pixmap(pTextEdit_title->size());
  pTextEdit_title->render(&pixmap);
  painter->drawPixmap(TextEditRect,pixmap);
```

It renders the `QLabel` file, but the problem is that it has gray background and doesn't act as transparent background. How can I set the `QLabel` background to be transparent? Also why has the TextInteractionFlags I've set been ignored? I can't do anything to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Color transparency depends on the value of the [`alpha` channel](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#alpha-blended-drawing) :

> The alpha channel of a color specifies the transparency effect, 0
>   represents a fully transparent color, while 255 represents a fully
>   opaque color.

By default it is 255 so you should specify the desired value as a fourth argument at the [`fromHsv`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#fromHsv) functions you are using.

Alternatively you could use the [`setAlpha`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#setAlpha) function.

Comment: how do i do that ? i didnt found any tutorial ?

Comment: i try to implement this :http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/QWidget_Semi-transparent_Background_Color.
but it still gray , i suspect it something to do with the background color i set to the item

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a widget, the widget background is always drawn. There is a special render flag to disable rendering of the widget background.

It is explained in the manual of the qwidget api.

Comment: yeah i did it with :
QPalette p(pTextEdit_title->palette());
  // Set background colour to black
  p.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::transparent);
  pTextEdit_title->setPalette(p);
still gray background ....

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

Eventually got it working by setting the attribute `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`on the widget before calling `widget->render()`